# How to add an x before each element in a list of strings so I can use it then in a lambda expression

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have the code I show below, where I make a dictionary after grouping by some columns. My goal is to transfer the mean I've calculated in the groupby dataframe to an other dataframe. For that I've created a dictionary. My problem is that I don't know how to make variable this part of the lambda expression: `x['year'],x['month'],x['quantity']`, so that if I change the variables I could change easily the expression. How can I add a x (as variable) to each element of a list? Or maybe I have to change all code to make it easier?

```
list = ['year','month']

m = data.groupby(list).agg({"quantity":"mean"}).reset_index()
d = m.groupby(list)["quantity"].apply(list).to_dict()
df["m"] = df.apply(
        lambda x: d[(x['year'],x['month'])][0]
        if (x['year'],x['month']) in d
        else 0,
        axis=1
    )
```

Comment: It would be useful if you gave example data and expected results. Your intention is not clear, For a start: you are grouping on `quantity` and then trying to aggregate on the same column which does not make sense.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have? It looks like you already "added an x" before each element.

Comment: You are right, I've changed the code, thank you. What I want is to have this part of the code variable, lambda x: d[(x['year'],x['month'])]so that if I change the variables in the list that change too. The list could have more than two variables in some occasions...

Comment: I want to change 'year' and ' month' in the lambda expression to be able to change the elements in the list, considering that the length of the list is not always the same